# How to give the delegate to the textfield in swift

Tags: ios

In my tableviewcell:-
i have uiview in that i have one textfield
I have other uiview in that i have label

So according to the type i will display the uiview in the tableviewcell.

So i got the output .But my problem is.

First cell i have textfield next cell have displaying only label.

I have given the delegate method in the tableviewcell.
So after typing the text in the textfield ,i pressed the ENTER key from the keyword.Then it ok.But while without pressing the ENTER key i choose the 2nd cell.So here the data is not entering how to do?

Comment: where is your code? add your code first

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tableViewController as the delegate, your tableViewController should adopt a protocol, UITextFieldDelegate, like this.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

As to each textfield, you have to assign:
  
    `textField1.delegate  = self 
    textField2.delegate  = self
    // self is the tabeleViewController here`

If you have two textfields, you can monitor them in one delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print (textField) // They should be different each time you click a textfield.
}
```

[image]

By this way, you can know where your problem is. Hope it's helpful.